# D3 chart - How can I put the X-axis below the Y-axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multiline, yaxis

I want my X-axis to be at the bottom of the graph but when why data is set to zero then it comes to the center of Y-axis? How do I prevent it from going to the center??

[image: my graph]

```
let x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])

x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.timescale; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(trends, function (c) {
  return d3.max(c.values, function (v) {
    return v.total;
  });
})]);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code is use to create the axis, especially the `.domain()` part.

Comment: please check i have uploaded the domain for x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because the maximum extent of `y.domain` is undefined. As a fallback, the vertical axis gets centered.

To fix this problem, make sure that a value is set, the example below make the y scale to go between at least domains 0 and 1.

Once this is fixed, the x axis should be correctly positioned at the bottom of the chart area.

```
let maxExtent = Math.max(1, d3.max(trends, function (c) {
  return d3.max(c.values, function (v) {
    return v.total;
  });
}))

y.domain([0, maxExtent]);
```

Comment: the same issue i am getting fot a bar chart but on x axis the domain and scale are very much similar to this how can i bring my bar chart to left of X axis instead of center

Comment: thank you the above solution foe line chart worked like a charm!!!